# AVD manager disappeared under tools

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I installed Android studio on a laptop with Windows 10 the other day and everything worked fine. I was able to set up an emulator and everything else.

After relaunching the application the next day I noticed I don't have the AVD Manager option icon in the toolbox anymore and it is not available under the Tools  drop down menu.

I have since uninstalled Android studio and reinstalled it twice but the same thing happens. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Click on Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button.

Comment: There is nothing like Customize Perspective under "Window " in the tool bar

Comment: Same problem here, the Android Virtual Device management subsystem seems to be completely gone after Android Studio/SDK updated this morning.  Not only are the GUI buttons to get to it gone, but I can't run it from the filesystem either as the files are gone!

Comment: Same problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new (blank if you so desire) project in Android Studio.  Then you can use the Tools menu in Android Studio.  Go to Android and slide over to AVD Manager.